# JmsTransactionManager with more connectionFactories

Tags: spring, jms, transactionmanager, spring-jms

I was wondering if anyone can help me with a large problem, I'm trying to implement more jmsTransactionManagers with Spring 2.5.6, but it isn't working.

I got 5 connectionfactories because i have to read and write from 5 different environments. They are all in my queue xml bean, but because when I read messages from one queue and they don't fit with the options I do an rollback with the transaction manager.

So my question is, how can I configure more JmsTransactionManagers.

Comment: show your configuration rather than describing it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use JTA if you need transactional access to more than one JMS session. In that case, you wouldn't be using JmsTransactionManager at all, you would use a JtaTransactionManager and enlist all those connections in a distributed transaction. This assumes that all of your JMS connections are XA-compatible (often times the connection factory is different, e.g. ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory vs. ActiveMQConnectionFactory).

If you are not using an application server (glassfish, weblogic, jboss AS, etc.), you can deploy a standalone JTA implementation (atomikos or jboss TS). The configuration of each of them differ quite a bit but Spring does support most of them.

Answer (score -1):

you can add reference of connectionFactory to the transaction manager

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory1"></property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory2"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: that won't work, for transactions to work, you need to give Spring one PlatformTransactionManager, what you are doing here is valid syntax but the second JmsTransactionManager cannot be used